# BPMN Swimlane. Can I use technical system layers in swimlanes instead of using actors or roles?

Tags: bpmn

I have a system prototype, which I want to model in BPMN. That system has three layers: data layer, gui and business logic. Can I use these three layers names  as BPMN swimlanes names instead of using actors or roles?

http://blog.goodelearning.com/bpmn/common-bpmn-modeling-mistakes-swimlanes/
Says swimlanes are for an organizational role (e.g. developer, analyst and manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your work might have finished a long ago, but you are mixing Architecture with BPMN (Process design).

Application mapping is not part of business process design and this is a common mistake done by people missing E2E purpose and scope of process modeling and how it integrates with other domains.

for Architecture you might need to use some other language more specific to it, say Archimate which handles this requirement very well and global standard for modeling architecture.

Business architecture/process architecture and process design are separate entities. we should try not to mix them.

All the best for current assignments.

Answer (score 3):

1. As far as I understand it, the blog entry does **not** state that organizational roles cannot be IT systems. It even mentions *content management system* as one example for an organization (when discussing pools). Subsequently, a sub system of the content management system should be a perfectly valid candidate for a lane.
2. When it comes to technicalities, it's always good to refer to the [BPMN specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/). Regarding the usage of lanes, it states:

   *The meaning of the Lanes is up to the modeler. BPMN does not specify the usage of Lanes.* (page 306, respectively 336 in PDF document)

   So according to the specification, **you can use these three layer names as BPMN swimlane names.**