# BPMN Diagram - Drawing a Swim Lane as a Software System

Tags: bpmn

In most of the BPMN diagram online I can only see swim lane as something that involves human.

Can I have a swim lane as a software system?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can: [BPMN Swimlane. Can I use technical system layers in swimlanes instead of using actors or roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511938/bpmn-swimlane-can-i-use-technical-system-layers-in-swimlanes-instead-of-using-a)

Comment: @Timotheus.Kampik: Since it's a duplicate, this question should be closed. Please vote for closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in "https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/". Page 306, line 3

Comment: We use BPMN (Version 2.0.2 contains a minor change to Clause 15.) for (clause 2.2.1)  BPMN Process Types:

 Descriptive
 Analytic
 Common Executable

Analytic we use for CIM (Computation Independent Model).  

Lanes: A Lane is a sub-partition within a Pool and will extend the entire length of the Pool, eithervertically or horizontally (see on page 304). Lanes are used to organize and categorize Activities.

You have to declare categorization and diagram type (Executable or no). You can't mix this .